# Laravel-5.7: Undefined variable: cart

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to add to cart the the products, and when i click on add to cart then after saving it into cart it have to redirect to cart page, the products are adding to cart (saving into db cart table) but cart page says:   **Undefined variable: cart** `(View:`D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\ecom2\resources\views\products\cart.blade.php)

> code of ProductsController:

```
  public function addtocart(Request $request){
  $data = $request->all();
  //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

  if(empty($data['user_email'])){
    $data['user_email'] = '';
  }


  $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
  if(empty($session_id)){
      $session_id = str_random(40);
      Session::put('session_id',$session_id);
  }


  DB::table('cart')->insert(['product_id'=>$data['product_id'],'product_name'=>$data['product_name'],'product_code'=>$data['product_code'],'product_color'=>$data['product_color'],'price'=>$data['price'],'size'=>$data['size'],'quantity'=>$data['quantity'],'user_email'=>$data['user_email'],'session_id'=>$session_id]);

  return redirect('cart')->with('flash_message_success','Product has been added in Cart!');
}

public function cart(){
  $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
  $userCart = DB::table('cart')->where(['session_id'=>$session_id])->get();
  foreach ($userCart as $key => $product) {
    $productDetails = Product::where('id',$product->product_id)->first();
    $userCart[$key]->image = $productDetails->image;
  }
  return view('products.cart')->with(compact('userCart'));
}
```

cart.blade.php:

```
  @extends('layouts.frontLayout.front_design')
  @section('content')

 <!-- Cart -->
 <section class="cart bgwhite p-t-70 p-b-100">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Cart item -->
        <div class="container-table-cart pos-relative">
            <div class="wrap-table-shopping-cart bgwhite">
                <table class="table-shopping-cart">
                    <tr class="table-head">
                        <th class="column-1"></th>
                        <th class="column-2">Product</th>
                        <th class="column-3">Price</th>
                        <th class="column-4 p-l-70">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="column-5">Total</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td class="column-1">
                            <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
                                <img src="{{ 
    asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$cart->image) }}" alt="IMG- 
     PRODUCT">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        @foreach($userCart as $cart)
                        <td class="column-2">{{ $cart->product_name }}</td>
                        <td class="column-3">PKR: {{ $cart->price }}</td>
                        <td class="column-4">
                            <div class="flex-w bo5 of-hidden w-size17">
                                <button class="btn-num-product-down color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                                    <i class="fs-12 fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>

                                <input class="size8 m-text18 t-center num-product" type="number" name="quantity" value="{{ $cart->price }}">

                                <button class="btn-num-product-up color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                                    <i class="fs-12 fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="column-5">PKR: {{ $cart->price*$cart->quantity }}</td>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-25 p-b-25 bo8 p-l-35 p-r-60 p-lr-15-sm">
            <div class="flex-w flex-m w-full-sm">
                <div class="size11 bo4 m-r-10">
                    <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22" type="text" name="coupon-code" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                </div>

                <div class="size12 trans-0-4 m-t-10 m-b-10 m-r-10">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                        Apply coupon
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="size10 trans-0-4 m-t-10 m-b-10">
                <!-- Button -->
                <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                    Update Cart
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Total -->
        <div class="bo9 w-size18 p-l-40 p-r-40 p-t-30 p-b-38 m-t-30 m-r-0 m-l-auto p-lr-15-sm">
            <h5 class="m-text20 p-b-24">
                Cart Totals
            </h5>

            <!--  -->
            <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-b-12">
                <span class="s-text18 w-size19 w-full-sm">
                    Subtotal:
                </span>

                <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
                    $39.00
                </span>
            </div>

            <!--  -->
            <div class="flex-w flex-sb bo10 p-t-15 p-b-20">
                <span class="s-text18 w-size19 w-full-sm">
                    Shipping:
                </span>

                <div class="w-size20 w-full-sm">
                    <p class="s-text8 p-b-23">
                        There are no shipping methods available. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help.
                    </p>

                    <span class="s-text19">
                        Calculate Shipping
                    </span>

                    <div class="rs2-select2 rs3-select2 rs4-select2 bo4 of-hidden w-size21 m-t-8 m-b-12">
                        <select class="selection-2" name="country">
                            <option>Select a country...</option>
                            <option>US</option>
                            <option>UK</option>
                            <option>Japan</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="size13 bo4 m-b-12">
                    <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-15 p-r-15" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State /  country">
                    </div>

                    <div class="size13 bo4 m-b-22">
                        <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-15 p-r-15" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode / Zip">
                    </div>

                    <div class="size14 trans-0-4 m-b-10">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                            Update Totals
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--  -->
            <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-26 p-b-30">
                <span class="m-text22 w-size19 w-full-sm">
                    Total:
                </span>

                  <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
                    $39.00
                  </span>
              </div>

              <div class="size15 trans-0-4">
                <!-- Button -->
                <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                    Proceed to Checkout
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>

   @endsection
```

Comment: show the cart.blade.php page

Comment: you were passing userCart to blade or view thats why.you getting this error

Comment: initially it was working fine,and then i add the session_id init after adding session it showing this error. but session_id is also saving in db

Comment: @NabilFarhan cart.blabe.php page is in question now

Comment: you have $userCart in blade, you iterate over it and create your $cart but above the foreach you are using $cart->image, only that there $cart is undefined. So you need to move the foreach above it

Comment: thnx @MunteanuPetrisor

Answer (score 0):

It may also be the case where you have used $cart variable elsewhere on the page. It would be helpful if you gave the entire cart.blade.php because your @foreach is also not quite right, you have ended the loop before a closing  tag, and not opened the loop before an opening...

```
    @foreach($userCart as $cart)
     <tr>
      //your other elements consisting of $cart
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: complete cart file is in question

Comment: Here's  your issue.   

asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$cart->image) }}" alt="IMG- 
          PRODUCT">
You have used $cart->image, but you haven't sent $cart variable, you have sent $userCart. Either this should be inside your loop, or you may have some other image to display on that specific section stored in some other variable and use it there.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe if you change your cart function to the following, it will work.

```
public function cart(){
  $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
  $userCart = DB::table('cart')->where('session_id', $session_id)->get();
  foreach ($userCart as $key => $product) {
    $productDetails = Product::find($product->product_id);
    $product->image = $productDetails->image;
  }
  return view('products.cart', compact('userCart'));
}
```

Comment: check now @programmer0001

Comment: }
  return view('products.cart, compact('userCart'));
} this line has syntax error

Comment: Well, yes, i forgot a comma. check now. @programmer0001

Comment: Please accept this answer so it could be closed. @programmer0001

Answer (score 0):

Check your session if empty or not and do query in the models not in the controller
"object oriented programming laravel".